# Как программно получить все элементы из формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Передо мной встала задача получить все элементы в форме, включая [меню](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip?view=netframework-4.8) и [строку состояния](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=netframework-4.8) и другие у которых имеется свойство `Text`. Так как у каждого контрола имеется свойство [Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.8) (и у формы соответственно тоже), то я могу использовать нижеприведённый код для получения всех контролов формы и их потомков:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control grandChild in GetControls(childControl))
        {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
        yield return childControl;
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что у меню не имеется свойства Controls и для доступа к дочерним элементам необходимо использовать свойство [Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items?view=netframework-4.8). На данный момент не нашёл ничего другого, как проверять тип. Можно ли каким либо образом единообразно получать доступ ко всем элементам формы включая дочерние?

Comment: Как это меню не наследуется от Control? [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip?view=netframework-4.8) с вами категорически не согласна. И если посмотреть код генерируемый дизайнером студии - увидите что меню также добавляется в коллекцию Controls.

Comment: @rdorn поправил вопрос: проблема не в доступе к самому меню, а в доступе к его потомкам.

Comment: Свойство `Items` содержит не контролы (`Control`), а `ToolStripItem`. Они не унаследованы друг от друга, поэтому _невозможно_ добавить тулстрипайтем в последовательность контролов. Уточните, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov получить все элементы, у которых есть свойство Text. Я в курсе, что они не унаследованы, иначе и вопроса бы не было, и приведённый код работал бы.

Comment: Дальше вы что собираетесь с ними делать? Единообразно их обрабатывать никак не получится. / Если вам нужен именно Text, то может, следует возвращать коллекцию строк (string)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возвращать строки не пойдёт, т.к. нужен именно элемент для записи в Text. Скорее всего нужно будет использовать интерфейс...

Comment: Оно вам не для локализации случаем нужно? Если да, то тогда почему не используете готовые средства локализации? Просто заменить текст почти всегда плохая идея из-за разной длины слов в разных языках, это не считая направление письма. Разметка поплывет, если сделаете под один язык, а отображать будете на другом.

Comment: @rdorn да, нужно для локализации. Готовые средства локализации не используются, т.к. это имеющийся велосипед с квадратными колёсами. Языков всего 3 и при переводе имеется максимально возможная длина строки. Направление письма одно и то-же.

Comment: А вы как хотите: быстро но сложно или просто но помучиться? =) В первом варианте смотрите в сторону выделения модели с описанием всех интерфейсных элементов и делайте на нее биндинг, на выходе меняете строчку в модели - меняется строка в интерфейсе. Во втором случае - пишите вариативный обход дочерних элементов в зависимости от типа элемента.

Comment: @rdorn на данный момент склоняюсь ко второму варианту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство `Items` содержит элементы типа [ToolStripItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=netframework-4.8), а не [Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.8). Они не унаследованы друг от друга, поэтому невозможно добавить тулстрипайтем в последовательность контролов.

Общим непосредственным предком этих классов является [Component](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=netframework-4.8), у которого нет свойства `Text`. Ни один из интерфейсов, которые они реализуют, тоже не имеет такого свойства. Поэтому в лоб ваша задача не решается.

Вы пишете, что не нашли ничего другого, как проверять тип. Да, тип придётся проверять в любом случае. Можно делать это внутри вашего метода и прямо там же выполнять необходимые действия.

Но если хочется внутри метода лишь найти все необходимые объекты, а действия с ними произвести снаружи, то могу предложить следующий код:

```
public static IEnumerable<Component> GetComponents(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl is ToolStrip toolStrip)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStrip.Items)
                yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Component component in GetComponents(childControl))
                yield return component;
        }
        yield return childControl;
    }
}
```

Здесь мы получаем последовательность типа `Component`, хотя с таким же успехом это могут быть `object` - в любом случае далее придётся проверять их тип.

Можно избежать ручной проверки типов, используя `dynamic`:

```
foreach (var component in GetComponents(this))
{
    ((dynamic)component).Text = "something";
}
```

---

Это более-менее рабочий код, но остаётся много вопросов. Например, `ToolStrip` может содержать [ToolStripDropDownButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton?view=netframework-4.8), который не имеет свойства `Items`, но имеет `DropDownItems`. Сильно подозреваю, что по ним вы тоже хотели бы пройтись.

Всё это наводит на мысли, что вы не с той стороны подходите к решению некоей своей проблемы.

---

А вообще, я бы сделал два (или больше, с учётом `DropDown`ов) метода, один из которых возвращал бы `Control`, другой `ToolStripItem`, третий - `ToolStripDropDownItem`.

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении элемента MenuStrip средствами конструктора форм, IDE добавляет private поле соответствующего типа в ваш класс формы (можно посмотреть в FormName.Designer.cs).
Если вы хотите получить этот элемент из другой формы, можно попробовать использовать рефлексию:

```
FieldInfo menuStrip = myControl.GetType().GetField("menu_strip_field_name", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

или перебрать все поля Control'а, и забрать все с типом MenuStrip

```
List<MenuStrip> items = new List<MenuStrip>();
foreach(var item in myControl.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
   if(item.FieldType == typeof(MenuStrip))
   {
      items.Add((MenuStrip)item.GetValue(myControl));
   }
}
```

Comment: Из другой формы не нужно. Имя меню неизвестно. И Вы пробовали сами?

Comment: @XelaNimed в примере с перебором без имени исправил, попробуйте (Не работало, потому как объект FieldInfo честно возвращал свой тип FiledInfo в .GetType(), там нужно использовать его проперти FieldType)

Comment: @XelaNimed под "забрать" подразумевается нечто вида MenuStrip myStrip = (MenuStrip)item.GetValue(myControl); добавлю в ответ

Comment: Поправил ответ. Проблема была не с доступом к меню, а с доступом к его потомкам.